# Ajax response getting trimmed

Tags: ajax, encoding, jquery, ckeditor

I'm sending some html inserted in an  (with CKEditor) to a .php trough jQuery ajax() and have that PHP return the html formatted and put it back in the textarea.

This is the Ajax call

```
var elhtml = document.getElementById('products_description[1]');
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: 'elhtml=' + elhtml.value,
        url: 'categories_cleanup.php',
        success: function(data) {

            $('#textarea').val(data.message);

        }
    });
```

And this is the PHP

```
<?php
echo json_encode(array("message"=>strip_tags( $_POST['elhtml'], '<ul><li>')));  
?>
```

The problem is that when the html comes back it gets trimmed. 
So I start debugging and found that it always gets trimmed at the point where there's a special character. If I place the same HTML that the ajax sends to the PHP where the $_POST var is, the HTML gets back to the textarea just fine.

So the problem must be the trip from the textarea to the php.
The code get's trimmed anytime there's an ' , for example: It's ->  It's
The code form the PHP will come back from zero to the first appeareance of '  [...] It

Is this an ajax encoding issue?
I tried setting the ajax dataType to text but the same happens.

I don't think that has anything to do with PHP since it can handle it perfectly when the html was inserted in the php itself.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: how about just using echo strip_tags( $_POST['elhtml'], '<ul><li>'). Then on your javascript  $('#textarea').val(data);. and set dataType: "html"

Comment: Replace `'elhtml=' + elhtml.value` with `{elhtml: elhtml.value}` - otherwise you have to take care of escaping etc

Comment: or simply do `$("#textarea").load("categories_cleanup.php", { elhtml: elhtml.value } );`

Comment: another one if .html does not work `$.post("categories_cleanup.php",  { elhtml: elhtml.value },function(data){$("#textarea").val(data);});`

Comment: replacing with {elhtml: elhtml.value} worked perfectly. ThiefMaster, do you want to post it as an answer (not as a comment) so I can mark your answer like the correct one?. Thanks to the rest for also helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by ThiefMaster:

Replace 'elhtml=' + elhtml.value with {elhtml: elhtml.value} - otherwise you have to take care of escaping etc

Answer (score 0):

The curly quote isn't in ISO 8859, the default encoding. Try forcing PHP to send the header `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`.

You can check the headers used in AJAX transactions in the Net tab in Firebug (jQuery's ordinary AJAX requests also show up in the console).

Comment: Thanks Steven but that didn't work. I made the PHP log the information it gets from the ajax call and the log shows the html trimmed like when it comes back. 

This means that the trimming happens before it gets to the PHP so changing the PHP header response won't fix anything since the html is already trimmed.

Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Now that I think of, "Thanks anyway" sounds bad, like some irony, but it isn't... I really apreciate you trying to help.

Comment: @Juan: Have you ensured that the actual PHP file is stored in UTF-8?